This environment is externally managed
I am trying to install a package using pip, but when running the command pip3 install requests for example, I get the following error:
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a Python library that isn't in Homebrew,
    use a virtual environment:
    
    python3 -m venv path/to/venv
    source path/to/venv/bin/activate
    python3 -m pip install xyz
    
    If you wish to install a Python application that isn't in Homebrew,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. You can install pipx with
    
    brew install pipx
    
    You may restore the old behavior of pip by passing
    the '--break-system-packages' flag to pip, or by adding
    'break-system-packages = true' to your pip.conf file. The latter
    will permanently disable this error.
    
    If you disable this error, we STRONGLY recommend that you additionally
    pass the '--user' flag to pip, or set 'user = true' in your pip.conf
    file. Failure to do this can result in a broken Homebrew installation.
    
    Read more about this behavior here: <https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/>

I am unsure why this is happening, as it never happened before, and nothing I found online seems to help solve this problem.
For context, I am using MAC, and writing just pip doesn't work, only pip3 works.

Do you use a ve?

MacOS seems to adopt the guideline of package management, also see PEP 668.
Basically, you should not mix the Python packages installed by your system and yours packages installed for your Python development.
If you want to install a package system wide, install it with your OS package manager. If it's for you, use an environment manager (venv, conda or any variants / alternatives).
